# readers-write lock in vxWorks

Tags: synchronization, vxworks, locks

How to implement readers-writer lock in vxWorks?

Readers-Writer lock:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers-writer_lock

Answer (score 2):

VxWorks 6.6 and beyond has existing API's that implement that capability.  Search the Kernel or Application Programmer's Guide for Read/Write Semaphores.